# signature (parameter names) mismatch variables in form not in procedure: non-default variables in procedure not in form:

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I took a different approach and my issues is resloved.

I'm developing an oracle package, I have no compile issues but am getting run errors. which I listed above. I have several stored procedures to look up the students id, classes, total hours, and term. I have added the procedure that I have shown above and I get the signature (parameter names) mismatch variables in form not in procedure: non-default variables in procedure not in form:. I am new to packages and can't find the mismatch. Thanks for looking at my issue
Mon, 13 Mar 2017 14:08:46 GMT

Failed to parse target procedure

```
zbwrschd.p_stumajr: SIGNATURE (parameter names) MISMATCH
VARIABLES IN FORM NOT IN PROCEDURE: 
NON-DEFAULT VARIABLES IN PROCEDURE NOT IN FORM: COLL_IN, MAJR_IN,     `PROGRAM_IN, GPA_IN, HRS_IN`

  DAD name: PPRD
  PROCEDURE  : zbwrschd.p_stumajr
  URL        : http://jsudssbauva01.ad.admin:9004/pls/PPRD/zbwrschd.p_stumajr
  PARAMETERS :
  ===========

  ENVIRONMENT:
  ============
    PLSQL_GATEWAY=WebDb
    GATEWAY_IVERSION=2
    SERVER_SOFTWARE=Oracle-HTTP-Server-11g
    GATEWAY_INTERFACE=CGI/1.1
    SERVER_PORT=9004
    SERVER_NAME=jsudssbauva01.ad.admin
    REQUEST_METHOD=GET
    QUERY_STRING=
    PATH_INFO=/zbwrschd.p_stumajr
    SCRIPT_NAME=/pls/PPRD
    REMOTE_HOST=
    REMOTE_ADDR=172.25.181.53
    SERVER_PROTOCOL=HTTP/1.1
    REQUEST_PROTOCOL=HTTPS
    REMOTE_USER=www_user
    ORACLE_SSO_USER=
    OSSO_IDLE_TIMEOUT_EXCEEDED=
    OSSO_USER_GUID=
    HTTP_CONTENT_LENGTH=
    HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE=
    HTTP_USER_AGENT=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36
    HTTP_HOST=ssb-dev.ec.jsums.edu:9004
    HTTP_ACCEPT=text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
    HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING=gzip, deflate, sdch, br
    HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE=en-US,en;q=0.8
    HTTP_ACCEPT_CHARSET=
    HTTP_COOKIE=TESTID=set; SESSID=VjlYUkRZODA1NDAz; _ga=GA1.2.799716495.1477066068; accessibility=false; AWSELB=8B6BA5270CD7C225086EB0AC974CD51DE967250DCB339CB2FAFFB744788FCE910C55F784DFD15C6E7391929DF806A2289EEE108C7A9D6268FA71502B182E2854382ABF5BF7
    HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE=
    HTTP_REFERER=https://ssb-dev.ec.jsums.edu:9004/pls/PPRD/twbkwbis.P_GenMenu?name=bmenu.P_FacAdvrMnu
    HTTP_SOAPACTION=
    HTTP_ORACLE_ECID=
    HTTP_ORACLE_CACHE_VERSION=
    HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=
    WEB_AUTHENT_PREFIX=
    DAD_NAME=PPRD
    DOC_ACCESS_PATH=docs
    DOCUMENT_TABLE=wpg_document
    PATH_ALIAS=
    REQUEST_CHARSET=AL32UTF8
    REQUEST_IANA_CHARSET=UTF-8
    SCRIPT_PREFIX=/pls
    HTTP_IF_MATCH=
    HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL=
    SOAP_BODY=
    HTTP_X_ORACLE_DEVICE_CLASS=
    HTTP_X_ORACLE_DEVICE_ORIENTATION=
    HTTP_X_ORACLE_DEVICE_MAXDOCSIZE=
    HTTP_X_ORACLE_DEVICE=
    HTTP_X_ORACLE_ORIG_ACCEPT=
    HTTP_X_ORACLE_ORIG_USER_AGENT=
    HTTP_X_ORACLE_USER_LOCALE=
    HTTP_X_ORACLE_USER_NAME=
    HTTP_X_ORACLE_USER_DISPLAYNAME=
    HTTP_X_ORACLE_USER_USERKIND=
    HTTP_X_ORACLE_USER_AUTHKIND=
    HTTP_X_ORACLE_USER_DEVICEID=
    HTTP_X_ORACLE_USER_LOCATION_ADDRESSLINE1=
    HTTP_X_ORACLE_USER_LOCATION_ADDRESSLINE2=
    HTTP_X_ORACLE_USER_LOCATION_ADDRESSLASTLINE=
    HTTP_X_ORACLE_USER_LOCATION_BLOCK=
    HTTP_X_ORACLE_USER_LOCATION_CITY=
    HTTP_X_ORACLE_USER_LOCATION_COMPANYNAME=
    HTTP_X_ORACLE_USER_LOCATION_COUNTY=
    HTTP_X_ORACLE_USER_LOCATION_STATE=
    HTTP_X_ORACLE_USER_LOCATION_POSTALCODE=
    HTTP_X_ORACLE_USER_LOCATION_POSTALCODEEXT=
    HTTP_X_ORACLE_USER_LOCATION_COUNTRY=
    HTTP_X_ORACLE_USER_LOCATION_TYPE=
    HTTP_X_ORACLE_USER_LOCATION_X=
    HTTP_X_ORACLE_USER_LOCATION_Y=
    HTTP_X_ORACLE_SERVICE_HOME_URL=
    HTTP_X_ORACLE_SERVICE_PARENT_URL=
    HTTP_X_ORACLE_HOME_URL=
    HTTP_X_ORACLE_MODULE_CALLBACK_URL=
    HTTP_X_ORACLE_MODULE_CALLBACK_LABEL=
    HTTP_X_ORACLE_CACHE_USER=
    HTTP_X_ORACLE_CACHE_SUBID=
    HTTP_X_ORACLE_CACHE_AUTH=
    HTTP_X_ORACLE_CACHE_DEVICE=
    HTTP_X_ORACLE_CACHE_LANG=
    HTTP_X_ORACLE_CACHE_ENCRYPT=
    HTTP_X_ORACLE_ASSERT_USER=
{
    CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BANINST1."ZBWRSCHD"
    AS


    PROCEDURE p_stumajr(coll_in           STVCOLL.STVCOLL_DESC%type,

                        majr_in           STVMAJR.STVMAJR_DESC%type,
                        program_in        STVDEGC.STVDEGC_DESC%type,
                        gpa_in            SHRLGPA.SHRLGPA_GPA%type,
                        hrs_in            SHRLGPA.SHRLGPA_HOURS_EARNED%type
                         );
    END zbwrschd;
    /

    CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY BANINST1."ZBWRSCHD"
    AS

       curr_release        VARCHAR2 (10) := '8.3';
       dummy_x             VARCHAR2 (1) := '';
       term                stvterm.stvterm_code%TYPE;
       trm                 stvterm.stvterm_code%TYPE;
       hold_term           stvterm.stvterm_code%TYPE;
       term_descr          stvterm.stvterm_desc%TYPE;
       trm_desc            stvterm.stvterm_desc%TYPE;
       student_name        VARCHAR2 (250);
       pidm                NUMBER;
       msg_level           NUMBER := 3;
       stud_no_classes     NUMBER (8);
       row_count           INTEGER;
       tot_hours           NUMBER (8) := 0;
       hold_stupidm        spriden.spriden_pidm%TYPE;
       hold_stupidm_char   VARCHAR2 (30) DEFAULT NULL;
       msg                 VARCHAR2 (255);
       term_rec            stvterm%ROWTYPE;
       stud_id             spriden.spriden_id%TYPE;
       spriden_found       BOOLEAN := TRUE;
       msg_text            VARCHAR2 (1000) := NULL;



    PROCEDURE p_stumajr(coll_in          IN STVCOLL.STVCOLL_DESC%type,
                    majr_in          IN STVMAJR.STVMAJR_DESC%type,
                    program_in       IN STVDEGC.STVDEGC_DESC%type,
                    gpa_in           IN SHRLGPA.SHRLGPA_GPA%type,
                    hrs_in           IN SHRLGPA.SHRLGPA_HOURS_EARNED%type
                    )


IS
      regmsg         VARCHAR2 (50);
      pidm_val       NUMBER (8);
      xyz            VARCHAR2 (8) DEFAULT NULL;
      -- anchor_string   VARCHAR2 (500);

      --mohammad
      online_class   BOOLEAN := TRUE;
      onl_class      VARCHAR2 (1);
      --mohammad
   BEGIN
      /* Check for valid user */
      IF NOT twbkwbis.f_validuser (pidm)
      THEN
         RETURN;
      END IF;

      /* If stupidm has not been passed as a param, then try to get */
      /*  it from the general table, gorwprm   */
      IF xyz IS NULL
      THEN
         hold_stupidm_char := twbkwbis.f_getparam (pidm, 'STUPIDM');
      /* Otherwise, store the value of the param in GORWPRM */
      ELSE
         hold_stupidm_char := twbkbssf.f_decode_base64 (xyz);
         twbkwbis.p_setparam (pidm, 'STUPIDM', hold_stupidm_char);
      END IF;

      /* If stupidm came from the table, then change it to a number */
      IF hold_stupidm_char IS NOT NULL
      THEN
         hold_stupidm := TO_NUMBER (hold_stupidm_char, '999999999');
      END IF;

      /* Make sure a student PIDM has been selected */
      IF hold_stupidm IS NULL
      THEN
         p_facidsel (hold_term, 'zbwrschd.p_shdpage');
         RETURN;
      END IF;

      -- p_common_proc1;
      OPEN stuinfo_cur (hold_stupidm);

      FETCH stuinfo_cur INTO stud_id;

      IF stuinfo_cur%NOTFOUND
      THEN
         spriden_found := FALSE;
      END IF;

      CLOSE stuinfo_cur;



      trm := hold_term;

      OPEN sfrstcr_cntr_cur (hold_stupidm, hold_term);

      FETCH sfrstcr_cntr_cur INTO stud_no_classes;

      IF sfrstcr_cntr_cur%NOTFOUND
      THEN
         stud_no_classes := 0;
      END IF;

      CLOSE sfrstcr_cntr_cur;

      row_count := 0;

      OPEN get_term_desc_curr (hold_term);

      FETCH get_term_desc_curr INTO trm_desc;

      CLOSE get_term_desc_curr;



      HTP.
      p (
            '<br>Student ID:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;   <u>'
         || f_getspridenid (hold_stupidm)
         || '</u> <br>Student Name: <u>'
         || f_format_name (hold_stupidm, 'FMIL')
         || '</u><br>Term:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;        <u>'
         || trm_desc
         || '</u><br><br>');

      IF stud_no_classes > 0
      THEN
         twbkfrmt.
         p_tableopen (
            'DATAWITHBORDER',
            cattributes   => g$_nls.
                            get ('BWSKOAC1-0002',
                                 'SQL',
                                 'summary="This is the student''''s'' major"'),
            ccaption      => g$_nls.
                            get ('BWSKOAC1-0003', 'SQL', 'Student major:'));
         twbkfrmt.p_tablerowopen ();
         twbkfrmt.p_tablerowclose;
         twbkfrmt.p_tablerowopen ();
         twbkfrmt.p_tabledataheader ('College &nbsp;&nbsp;');
         twbkfrmt.p_tabledataheader ('Major &nbsp;&nbsp;');
         twbkfrmt.p_tabledataheader ('Program &nbsp;&nbsp;');
         twbkfrmt.
         p_tabledataheader ('GPA&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;');
         twbkfrmt.p_tabledataheader ('Hrs.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;');
         twbkfrmt.p_tablerowclose;

         twbkfrmt.p_tabledata (g$_nls.get ('BWRKSUM1-0909', 'SQL',COLL_in));
         twbkfrmt.p_tabledata (majr_in);
         twbkfrmt.p_tabledata (program_in);
         twbkfrmt.p_tabledata (gpa_in);
         twbkfrmt.p_tabledata (hrs_in);

       IF row_count > 0
         THEN
            twbkfrmt.p_tableclose;
         END IF;

         IF row_count > 0
         THEN
            OPEN sfrstcr_no_of_hrs_cur (hold_stupidm);

            FETCH sfrstcr_no_of_hrs_cur INTO tot_hours;

            IF sfrstcr_no_of_hrs_cur%NOTFOUND
            THEN
               tot_hours := 0.00;
            END IF;

            CLOSE sfrstcr_no_of_hrs_cur;

            HTP.br;
            HTP.
            bold (
                  'Total Credit Hours: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'
               || tot_hours
               || '');
            HTP.br;
         END IF;
      ELSE
         HTP.br;
         msg_text := TO_CHAR ('The student has not selected classes yet. ');
         twbkfrmt.p_printmessage (msg_text, 2);
         msg_text := NULL;
      END IF;
   END p_stumajr;

   /*--------------------------------------------
    p_stumajr
   ---------------------------------------------*/
    END zbwrschd;
/
```

I removed everything but the procedure that is giving me the error.  Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: PLEASE DO NOT SHOUT.

Comment: Sorry, I just copied the error for where I run the package.

Comment: @OldProgrammer. I guess only in email writing etiquette specifies writing CAPS as SHOUTING. Not all the time CAPS can be considered as SHOUTING, And this post is absolutely not an email.

Comment: @Don_Boles. You must tell the context of your problem first. What are you trying to do and what issue you got. Looking at your post i couldnot make out what is your problem. No one can read your 1000 lines code and provide solution. Be short and simple

Comment: I'm developing an oracle package, I have no compile issues but am getting run errors. which I listed above.  I have several stored procedures to look up the students id.  I have added the procedure that I have shown above and I get the  signature (parameter names) mismatch variables in form not in procedure: non-default variables in procedure not in form:.  I am new to packages and can't find the mismatch.  Thanks for looking at my issue.

Comment: Oracle provides a good error stack for reference. Could you plz provide that as just looking into 1000 line code and no specific error, its very difficult. Also plz try to be very specific while asking any question.